# How to detect monitor number in the correct order on windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am creating a WPF application and I need the app to correctly detect the monitor number.
In my setup the monitor order is the one shown here

[image].

I tried using `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens`, but the system detects the monitor 2 as Display1 and monitor 1 as Display2. I think that this is related to the fact that my screen is extended from monitor 2 to monitor 1, but I need that the monitor number is correctly detected independently from the setup.
I also tried using C++ with `EnumDisplayDevices` or `EnumDisplayMonitors` but I always obtain the same incorrect result.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no reliable way to identify the monitor index used in the settings dialog.